# Have no idea how to include a tex file into another tex file

Tags: include, multiple-files

I would like to include a tex file into another tex file. However, I failed to use the `\include{}` command in this case. What command should I use to input the content of `PR1.tex` below `\section{Problem1}`?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve by "including" a latex document, say, `doc1.tex`, in another latex document, say,`doc0.tex`. (I'll assume that `doc1.tex` compiles correctly and without errors.) Are you trying to include the *pdf output* of `file1` in `file0`, or are you trying to include the *source code*? Please advise.

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks so much for your reply. I am not familiar with the terminology of LaText so my expression is not very clear, I am so sorry for it. I am trying to include the doc1.tex, the source code exported from the Jupyter into the doc0.tex. :)

Answer (score 1):

A LaTeX document can have only one `\documentclass` instruction, only one set of `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` instructions, only one `\maketitle` instruction, etc. That's why it's not possible to directly include `PR1.tex` in its entirety in `main.tex`.

To make some progress, I suggest you begin by creating two new tex files named, say, `PR1preamble.tex` and `PR1body.tex` and fill them with the preamble material and the body material of ``` PR1.tex``. Next, change ``` PR1.tex` so that it looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input PR1preamble
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\input PR1body
\end{document}
```

Do verify that this new, slimmed down driver file compiles correctly.

Finally, edit the file `main.tex` so that it includes two `\input` statements rather than just one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input PR1preamble
% other preamble instructions
\begin{document}
\maketitle
% some stuff
\input PR1body
% more stuff
\end{document}
```

If there's some overlap (or even conflict) between the material of `PR1preamble.tex` and the preamble of `main.tex`, you'll need to figure out which material to keep and which material to drop.