# Combine two different \documentclass and different packages in one document

Tags: standalone, article, books

This is my main document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \newpage
    \input{Untitled-1}
\end{document}
```

And this is my second document "Untitled-1"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mmacells, tipa, esint,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=6cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{mmaCell}[morefunctionlocal={R}, morelst={breaklines=true}]{Input}
\{Integrate[Sqrt[\mmaUnd{R}] E^(\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\sigma}\)} t), \{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\phi}\)}, 0, \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\phi}\)0}\}], Limit[\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\sigma}\)} E^(\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\sigma}\)} t)/Sqrt[R],R\(\pmb{\to}\)\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}]\}
\end{mmaCell}
\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
\{\mmaSup{e}{t\(\sigma\)}\mmaSqrt{R} \(\phi\)0, 0\}
\end{mmaCell}
\end{document}
```

as you can see, i'm trying to use standalone package without including the packages from my second doc to the main doc. But it doesn't work. I really need to split my document like this since i'm facing a lot of problem with crashing packages and i don't want to delete one of them.

Comment: Does [Have no idea how to include a tex file into another tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580123/5001) help?

Comment: @Mico thanks for the reply. But sadly no. Sorry. I need to include my second document with packages that crash with the main document. It's like when i want to put tikz picture on my main document in that case i'm using two documentclass that is standalone and in my case it's a book class.. I'm certainly sure (perhaps) i can use something like standalone package or newclude package, etc. But i just don't know how. I've tried all possibilites that i knew and still doesn't work. And i'm afraid i can't drop one of my package.

Comment: Your apparent insistence on including the second document, without modification, in the first document is doomed. A (compilable) LaTeX document must contain one *and only one* `\documentclass` instruction, one preamble, one *and only one* `document` environment, etc.

Comment: standalone (which is a very tricky package introducing a lot of dependencies) can help avoid edit the preambles in some cases but the end result is still the document being input with a merged preamble so can not solve package clashes if there are any. Just `\input` the body of the included document and resolve any package dependencies in the preamble of the main document.

Comment: I don't have the packages to test but replace `standalone` in the main document by `\usepackage{mmacells, tipa, esint,amsmath}`  and delete everything but the content of the `document` environment in `Untitled-1` then if you get any errors, you could ask about those.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for reply. But sadly that's not my point. If it's possible, i just want to use different `\documentclass` with different packages and include the second document into the main document "without putting packages" from second document to the main document. I know it sounds stupid but if there's a way to use conflicting packages in one document, why not?

Comment: there is no way of doing that in general. standalone/import/whatever just do some syntactic tricks to possibly make it easier to combine documents but they still _combine_ all the definitions, if you are specifying conflicting definitions then you need to resolve them, and then it is much easier to resolve them in the simple input case rather than working out exactly how standalone has combined things and customising that.